# Devexpress - GridControl - Tab Key - I Want Tab Move From Right To Left

Tags: c#, database, devexpress, gridcontrol

Please i am using Dev-express Grid Control and now i want when the user press on [ Tab ] Move to next Cell in the Same Row From Right to left

i tried some ways but failed to success my issue goal 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example that shows how to implement a custom navigation logic:

[How to change the default navigation algorithm in GridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3185)